# JavaFX issue when placing square at coordinates

Tags: javafx

so i have the following code from a Rectangle

```
rect.setX(10);
```

and I also have

```
rect.setY(20);
```

but whenever i compile the application the rectangle is always moved to the middle of the application's frame.

Imports used:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

Comment: What is the layout you are using to place the rectangle on the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the rectangle is added to a `StackPane`, you must use the translate properties to move the rectangle. Try :

```
rect.setTranslateX(10);
rect.setTranslateY(20);
```