# Is it possible to put ImageView on Canvas in JavaFX?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, popup, imageview

I am a newbie to javafx. I am developing an application in which I have a canvas and I have drawn several images in it. I want to add an `ImageView` on my canvas and implement a popup while clicking on the ImageView?

Is there any possibilities with or without `ImageView` (buttons or any controls?) or is it restricted to use controls over canvas?

I need some suggestions please.

Comment: Do you want to place the `ImageView` on top of `Canvas`?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : Yes !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can stack an `ImageView` on top of a `Canvas`. Use a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html). You can later add mouse listeners to the `ImageView`.

> Is there any possibilities with or without `ImageView` (buttons or any controls?) or is it restricted to use controls over canvas?

All controls including `Button`, `ImageView` and `Canvas` itself extend from [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) and can be used to add in the `StackPane`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    int count = 1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene s = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gc.fillRect(10, 10, 300, 300);

        ImageView image = new ImageView("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toys/256/teddy_bear_toy_6.png");

        // Listener for MouseClick
        image.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            Stage popup = new Stage();
            popup.initOwner(stage);
            popup.show();
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, image);

        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Output:

- Scene has Black Background
- Canvas has Blue Background
- ImageView is the bear.

[image]

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot for the solution .. I have a doubt , consider I am using an anchorpane as parent, inside that can I use this stackpane and rest of the operations?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just add StackPane as the child of AnchorPane.

Comment: Hi i have added imageview but I cannot position it with the x and y co ordinates , it always appears in the center. I have used setLayoutX and setLayoutY  properties . How to position it?

Comment: Please go through [JavaFX : How to position a component/node?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29934733/1759128) and once you are done with it, go through [JavaFX issue when placing square at coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29716180/1759128)

Comment: Yes setTranslateX and setTranslateY works !!!    thumps up !                 but still taking the values with respect to the center of the stackpane , is it like that?

Comment: Oops yes translation w.r.t. origin ryt ? :)

Comment: I didn't get your question. Using a StackPane will always place their children in the center and to move them you can use translate properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want add button, image ... on the top of your canvas you should use [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html). 
You first add your canvas and then you can add Button or whatever you want.

```
 StackPane stack = new StackPane();
 stack.getChildren().addAll(yourCanvas, yourButton);
```

You should read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) for a better understanding of Layouting with JavaFX.